# String to const char* in Arduino?

Tags: c++, c, string, char, arduino

I have a variable `tweet` that is  a string and it has a character at the very beginning that I want to clip off.

So what I want to do is use `strstr()` to remove it. Here's my code:

```
tweet = strstr(tweet, "]");
```

However, I get this error:

```
cannot convert 'String' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 
'char' strstr(const char*, const char*)
```

So my thought would be to convert `tweet` into a char. How would I go about doing so?

Comment: Use the `c_str()` method to get a `const char*`

Comment: Have a look at the definition of `String` and see if there's a suitable function (like the `c_str()` member function of `std::string`) - hopefully there'll be some way to do what you want without messing around with C-style strings. Without knowing what `String` is, this question can't be answered.

Comment: @Andrew why did you remove the arduino tag? That removed important information from the question!

Comment: Writing multi-language source files is hard work. I suggest you stick to one of C or C++.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about you use `substring` instead.  This will be less confusing than converting between different types of string.

http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringSubstring

Comment: +1 for recognizing Arduino String class instead of c++ std::string

Answer (score 26):

`string` has a `c_str()` member function that returns `const char *`.

Comment: Technically this is the correct answer if one reads what the OP was asking.  How to convert to a c string because some apis require that , and from a capital S  string, not std::string.  [API reference](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/c_str/)

Answer (score 1):

you can do that easier. Since you're using C++:

```
tweet = tweet.substring(1);
```

substr() returns a part of the string back to you, as string.
The parameter is the starting point of this sub string.
Since string index is 0-based, 1 should clip off the first character.

If you want to use strstr you can just cast tweet into a c-string:

```
tweet = strstr( tweet.c_str(), "]" );
```

However, that's pretty inefficient since it returns a c-string which has to be turned into a std::string against in order to fit into tweet.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question, but if you're trying to, say, compare a specific char, and not just one letter in a string, then what you want is *string*.charAt(n). For example, if you're doing serial programming and you need to check for STX (\02) than you can use the following code.

```
char STX = '\02'

if (inputString.charAt(0) == STX) {
  doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following statement `tweet.c_str()` will return the string buffer, which will allow you to perform the edit you want.

Answer (score 0):

Look at:

```
string.indexOf(val)
string.indexOf(val, from)
```

Parameters

```
string: a variable of type String
val: the value to search for - char or String
from: the index to start the search from
```

[See this page](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringIndexOf)